# SKLabelNode with stroke color

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

Does anyone know if its possible to add a stroke/border color to an SKLabelNode?

Looking at the API I don't see anything that will allow this.

Comment: Nope, bitmap fonts can provide that though. Glyph Designer will soon work with Sprite Kit if it isn't already.

Comment: also http://www.bmglyph.com/todo-list/ should be out soon